# output data, dynamic sql

Tags: sql, plsql

I have some problem with dynamic SQL.
I created table, after that inserted some data - it works fine.
But i have no idea how to display data. My code:

```
declare
begin
execute immediate 'create table name(tabl_name varchar2(30),id number)';

execute immediate 'insert into name(tabl_name,id) (select ''something'',id from table3)';
commit;
```

and now i would like to display name table content. How to do that? Should i use cursor with dynamic sql? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can't you just do 'select * from table_name'?

Comment: Without `into` clause one cannot use `select *....` in anonymous block in `PLSQL`

Answer (score 1):

You can use cursor to loop through the records:

```
declare
    v_tabl_name varchar2(30);
    v_id number;
    res_cur SYS_REFCURSOR;
begin
    execute immediate 'create table name(tabl_name varchar2(30),id number)';
    execute immediate 'insert into name(tabl_name,id) (select ''something'',id from table3)';
    open res_cur for 'select tabl_name, id from name';

    LOOP
       FETCH res_cur INTO v_tabl_name, v_id;
       EXIT WHEN res_cur%NOTFOUND;
       dbms_output.put_line(v_tabl_name);
       dbms_output.put_line(v_id);
    END LOOP;

    close res_cur;

end;
```